# Pandas Profiling: IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Tags: pandas, jupyter, index-error, pandas-profiling

Screenshot showing the error: IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

[image: 1]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which in your case is a code snippet not a screenshot. Moreover, it is supposed to be "minimal" in the sense that it is isolated not requiring datasets/dependencies not shared in the code snippet.

Comment: Please consult [this threat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34952651/only-integers-slices-ellipsis-numpy-newaxis-none-and-intege) and others on SO to see if the problem you encountered is unique.